# How to export multiple layers as an single image file? [PSD]

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I am a web developer that was given a PSD file (a web page design) that I need to convert to XHTML/CSS.

In the psd file, the logo is a group of multiple layers, each layer representing an element of that logo. I can only export layers to separate files.

My problem is: How I can export multiple layers to a single image file, so I can get a single logo.gif? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an animated gif, follow these steps:

1. open you PSD file
2. in Photoshop, go the menu window > animation
3. this panel helps with the animations, and I suggest you turn it into a frame animation it's easier for a begginer, to do that, in the animation panel, click in the top right icon and chose the "convert to frame animation".
4. in this animation window, you can add frames and specify the time of each and if it loops, etc.

Note that if a specific layer is visible, that layer will appear in the frame selected, and so on (to make the layers visible just click on the eye icon.

When you're done, (and you can test your animation by clicking in the "play" button, etc), you will save the gif, just go to the file menu > save for web, and here select gif, and on the right column, at the bottom, indicate which type of animation, loop, etc.

Make a few tries and you'll get the hang of it :)

Answer (score 1):

File -> Save as... "Compuserve GIF"

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple layers to a file, you just save the file normally. If you only want a few certain layers, then you turn off the visibility for those you don't need, then save it.

Answer (score 1):

Hide all the unwanted layers which you don't need in your logo, then crop the document (cover the area of the logo only), then save it as GIF.

Comment: would this way lost the transparency of image?

Comment: if you need background just activate the background layer and if you dont need background just hide it.transparency will remain when there is no background.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step-by-step guide to export multiple layers as an single image file:

1. Select the Layers which all you like to see in the final image from layers
   palette.
2. Then right click in the layers palette and select the option "Group
   as..".
3. Give a name for the group and press OK.
4. Now you will see a group in the Layers palette with your given name.
5. Select this group and right click and select "Export as..".
6. Save it in the format you like and you will get the image only with
   selected layers.