# layered icon in PSD into vectorized image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, vector, mobile

I made an icon via combining multiple layers of shapes by using magic wand, rectangle tool and circle tool, all this in PSD.

Now, how can i convert that into a vector SVG that can be used on a website or mobile app?

I've looked at some similar questions such as  [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/extracting-layers-from-psd?rq=1)  and [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/how-to-export-multiple-layers-as-an-single-image-file-psd) but because I'm a developer that is new to working with graphics and photoshop, I'm not entire sure what I should do.

Comment: Hi there! Can you upload an image of your graphic? It would also help if you tell us why the answers in those two questions you mention didn't help. Which steps are giving you trouble?

Comment: The typical solution is to redraw it in vector format. There may be ways to automate that to some extent (auto-tracing) but it really depends on the particular image we're talking about.

Comment: Generally speaking, I would try to start the workflow the other way around — **starting** with vector information (i.e. from Illustrator), and bringing it into Photoshop from there. The reason that a couple other commenters are suggesting you redraw from scratch it is that pixel (PSD) and vector (SVG) information are entirely different formats. EDIT: Here's a good article on the subject — http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/pixel-vector-graphics-difference/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, There are two methods to make your raster image into vector image.

1. Open your design in Adobe Illustrator and select it, now you would get some options below the main menu bar *"Image Trace"*. Click on that button and your image would be in vector.
   **Note : Your design must be in high resolution in order to convert it into vector otherwise it won't work. You would still need to refine the edges of design to make it look same as before**

   [image]
    *As you see in this image. The design is in raster form and selected and an option in blue circle.*
2. You will have to redraw it.

*I am user of Adobe Illustrator CS 6 and this answer is based on that version.*

Comment: Like Tester mentioned above, I would redraw it in Illustrator. Import the image to illustrator and set the layer to template, this will fade the image back a bit so you can see your outlines. The redraw. I would waste much time with the Trace tool. Play with it a bit but your results will be much improved if you just redraw it. It'll look better too.